# Is it possible for a thread to execute before another line in main that comes before it?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization

Would it be possible for this code to print out:

--> console-output:

```
Thread-1 printed
main printed
```

--> Code:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
System.out.println("main printed");
new Thread( () -> System.out.println("Thread-1 printed")).start();
}
```

In my opinion this code should be able to print out either

```
Thread-1 printed
main printed
```

or

```
main printed
Thread-1 printed
```

because i think that it would be possible for the other thread to simply be faster than the main thread for whatever reason. Is this assumption true or false?

I tried the code various times but only got the result where main printed before the thread-1.
But i still think that in theory it would be possible because there is no "join()" or something else that is called on main-thread.

Comment: `Thread#start()` creates a [_happens-before_ relationship](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility).

Comment: This has nothing to do with thread execution; it is just the sequential execution of program statements.

Comment: why? ..........

Answer (score 2):

This code will always print

```
main printed
Thread-1 printed
```

no matter how fast Thread-1 executes, as Thread-1 is only created/started after the line `System.out.println("main printed");`. Your main method is still synchronous with the `System.out.println("main printed")` instruction being called before `new Thread( () -> ...)` creating the thread in the first place. That order will not change.

The order could, in theory, change if `System.out.println("main printed")` was also wrapped in a thread and ran in parallel to the other thread, assuming the second print would for some reason take longer than the first one.

Comment: So it is also not possible that the time that the command "println(main started)" takes to actually get executed is longer than the time it takes for the second thread to print "thread-1 printed"?

Comment: @Wasserentzug Your thread is started **after** the call to `println("main started")` has returned (i.e., completed). In other words, `println("main started")` _happens-before_ the call to `start()`, which _happens-before_ `println("thread-1 printed")`.